# Is the function $N×N$ to $N$ surjective given by $(x,y) ↦ x$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Is the function $N × N$ to $N$ surjective given by $(x,y) ↦ x$?

And if it is, why?

I know that a function f:S->T is surjective iff for all t that belong to T there exists s that belongs to S with t=fs.

Comment: Do you know what it means for a function to be surjective?

Comment: It means that every element of the target set has to be mapped by at least one element of the source set

Comment: Let $x ∈ N$ be of the target set. Can you think of an element of the source set that maps to $x$?

Comment: the first element of (x,y), that is x ???

Comment: Your answer is unclear to me. What is $y$? What exactly is your guess for an element of $N × N$ that maps to $x$?

Comment: I didn't understand can I receive more explanation please.

Comment: JhonDoe: Why don't you expand your question (and provide more context) by including, in your posted question, what you know to be the definition of a surjective function?  Surely you must have a definition available in your notes and/or text(s).  What must be true about your function in order for it to be surjective?  When stuck, begin with definitions.

Comment: Actually, no. Try to pinpoint what part of my question you do not understand and try to phrase a precise question yourself. Otherwise, I’d just be either guessing what your problem is or giving you a solution you can definitely come up with yourself – and that would be a shame.

Comment: I know that a function f:S->T is surjective iff for all t that belong to T there exists s that belongs to S with t=fs.    Can I chose like x=j and y=k where k,j are natural numbers, and write:  
(j,k) -> j . Is this correct to prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that a function is *surjective* if every element of the target set is in the range of the function. Your function takes pairs $(x,y)$ of elements from $N$ and maps the pair to the first coordinate. So the question is: In the set of *all pairs of elements from $N$*, does every element of $N$ appear as the first component of a pair?

Comment: I think yes. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes. If you can explain why, you have your answer. A good way to explain it would be to, given an element $x \in N$, supply a *specific* pair in $N \times N$ that is mapped to it.

Comment: Can I chose like x=j and y=k where k,j are natural numbers, and write:

Comment: (j,k) -> j ?   is this correct to prove it?

Comment: Sure, that'll work. It'd be simpler to choose one particular option for $y$, but that's fine. But when you're writing it up, be *precise* about what the various letters mean.

Comment: What do you mean with more precise. And I also wanted to ask you if at the end I can add that j(source set) = j (target set)

Comment: By "more precise", I mean that you should be specific about how you're selecting these. Are $k$ and $j$ allowed to be *any* natural number? Or must they be a specific natural number? And so on. As for your other question, I have no idea what "j(source set) = j(target set)" means; that's not standard notation. So no, don't use that.